# Creating dynamic array to hold many words

Tags: c, arrays

Hello again everyone I am doing a C project related to my course. I need to define a dynamic array to hold words and the word number may be very large as 7 million but word length is at most 100 characters. I have created dynamic array as:

```
char (*words)[1001];
words = (char (*)[1001]) malloc(sizeof(*words));
```

And I am adding words to this array as:

```
while(!feof(mergefile))
    {
        if (EOF!=fscanf(mergefile,"%s",word)){
            strcpy(words[index] , word);
            index++;
        }
    }
```

But I am getting segmentation fault when I try many words to be added. My question is that how can I correctly create this array to hold many words?

Please help me because time is limited , thank you..

Comment: Don't cast the return value of `malloc()`. --- You have only allocated memory for one strings, you will need to `malloc(sizeof(*words) * NUMBER_OF_STRINGS);`.

Comment: But I do not know the NUMBER_OF_WORDS , because teacher will run code and I do not know how many words there will be. So what can I do?

Comment: *somehow* you know the number of words. If not at compile time, then at runtime.

Comment: If the number of words to be read is kept in a variable, say `int number_of_words`, then you can allocate the array with `words = malloc(number_of_words * sizeof(*words));`

Comment: Actually my question is how can I correctly create string array in c because it does not work!

Comment: Look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20274801/i-m-trying-to-sort-the-node-by-score-i-do-not-know-what-error-i-am-having/20305243#20305243 modify the struct to just store one string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){
    char **words = malloc(7000000*sizeof(char*));
    if(words){
        FILE *mergefile = stdin;//mock
        char word[100+1];
        size_t index = 0;

        while(!feof(mergefile)){
            if(EOF!=fscanf(mergefile, "%100s", word)){
                words[index]=malloc(strlen(word)+1);
                if(words[index]==NULL){
                    puts("I can't continue ...\n");
                    exit(-1);
                }
                strcpy(words[index++], word);
            }
        }
        words = realloc(words, index*sizeof(char*));
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<index;++i){
            puts(words[i]);
            free(words[i]);
        }
        free(words);
    } else {
        puts("I can't...\n");
    }
    return 0;    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're trying to declare `words` to be a pointer to an array of 1001-character strings, which I think is part of what's giving you trouble in the declarations. I'd recommend instead declaring `words` this way:

```
char **words;
words = malloc(number_of_words * sizeof(char *));
```

and writing your loop to `strdup` each word instead of `strcpy`ing it:

```
while(!feof(mergefile))
{
    if (EOF!=fscanf(mergefile,"%s",word)){
        words[index] = strdup(word);
        index++;
    }
}
```