# How Do you create an Linked lists of linked lists

Tags: c

I am new to this and I am just looking for feedback.

I have currently created a struct as follows

```
struct node{
    int value;
    int power;
    struct node *link;
};
```

and from this I created a linked list, to represent 1 quadratic. However the bit that I am having a problem with is that I am struggling to make lists of these lists to represent an indefinite amount of quadratic.

Comment: I suggest you do a bit of looking at the many many questions there are on linked lists in c on SO.  Just type ``[c] linked list`` into the search box.  I've answered a few, here is my favourite http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20274801/i-m-trying-to-sort-the-node-by-score-i-do-not-know-what-error-i-am-having/20305243#20305243

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need a second structure, maybe like this:

```
struct node_list
{
    struct node *equation;
    struct node_list *next;
};
```

The `equation` member hold a pointer to an equation (quadratic, list of `struct node`), while `next` points to the next `struct node_list`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, the bit that I am struggling with in doing this, is that I know the size of each block in my linked list for the quadratic. But how to I get the size of each quadratic and suppose the user wanted to insert an large polynomial. How would I get the size for each block in my linked list

Comment: Why wouldn't you use `sizeof(struct node_list)`?  I'm not clear what you're doing with your quadratics; it could be, I suppose, that you allocate `3 * sizeof(struct node)` and then hook the pieces together, but if you're doing that, you're wasting space. You could simply store 3 coefficients in a simple non-list structure.

Comment: Sorry Jonathon I wanted to create a program that could also take into account polynomials of any degree, however I just thiught it would have been easier to have got hints for a quadratic. But I think i was being too vague

Comment: OK; the equations of general degree is fine.  There's no real difference when using the linked lists.  You'd be using `struct node_list *next_equation = malloc(sizeof(*next_equation));` to allocate an element of the list of equations. `next_equation->next = 0; next_equation->equation = current_equation;` (given `struct node *current_equation = …;`) and then you add `next_equation` to your list of equations.